# Value of type 'Error' has no member 'code'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, nserror

I am moving a test application over to Xcode 8 Beta 5 and converted my code to Swift 3. I am left with a few errors regarding the switch to `Error` from `NSError`. I get an error in Xcode saying, `'Value of type 'Error' has no member  'code'`. I can still use `localizedDescription`. Is `code` no longer a value within `Error` or is it just a bug within Xcode?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Figured the answer out on my own minutes later. Xcode decided to give me a `did you mean` suggestion and `.code` is now `._code`.

Comment: I think it's a bug.

Comment: error?._code will be exactly correct and works for me...!

Comment: So strange naming convention. Thanks anyway. It works.