# How do you deal with error codes in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nserror

as `NSError` has become `Error` in Swift 3.0 how do you deal with error codes? For example:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }
```

Gives the message `Value of type Error has no member code`. Should I cast it to `NSError?`

Comment: Found two similar questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711269/accessing-code-in-swift-3-error, and there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908667/value-of-type-error-has-no-member-code?rq=1

Comment: please put the `._code` instead of `.code`